# SharePoint PowerShell script to trim new lines

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I have a column in a SharePoint list with many newlines, including in the beginning of text. I want to remove only first two newlines i.e. those in the beginning of the text as they are meaningless.

Is there a way to do it with the trim function? I can't use replace as it will replace all the newlines. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String-objects have a `TrimStart()`-Method that you could use to remove whitespace and newlines.

```
$s = @"


  test
"@

#Trim all whitespace and newlines before the text.
$s.TrimStart()
```

Output:

```
test
```

The solution above may remove too much. To remove only two newlines (0-2 newlines), try the regex below.

```
$s = @"


  test
"@

$s -replace '^[\n\r]{0,4}'
```

Output:

```
  test
```

I'm not sure how you're input will look line (multi-line string vs. string-array, newline and/or Carriage Return etc.) so the answer may need to be modified.

Comment: It worked perfectly. But I was wondering why \n and \r both are used?? and since we want to remove only 2 new lines why have we used {0,4}? Just an update.. I tried it with '^[\n]{0,2}' and it gave me the same result !

Comment: It depends on your input. In the Windows-world, linebreaks are defined as CR+LF (`\r\n`), while Linux usually just use `\r`. That's why I ended my answer With saying that you may need to modify it. :) The regex in my answer allows 0 to 4 characters (which can only be `\r` or `\n`), so if you only need `\n` for you input data, then change it to `'^[\n]{0,2}'`